# Renaming with list with magrittr

Tags: r, magrittr

I've been playing with magrittr, and I really like the resulting code. It's clean and can really save on typing.

How can I rename list elements in magrittr:

In typical base R:

```
data_lists <- paste0("q",2011:2015)
data_lists <- lapply(data_lists,get)
names(data_lists) <- paste0("q",2011:2015)
```

In magrittr, I thought:

```
data_lists <- 
   paste0("q",2011:2015) %>%
   lapply(.,get) %>%
   names(.) %<>% paste0("q",2011:2015) # this is wrong
```

But... no dice.

Comment: Downvote without a comment, bad form.

Comment: Maybe it's a good idea to make the question (and answer) more general? Your example can be ignored if you use `setNames` like suggested below, but other types of names (like rownames) and even other aliases can't (unless you follow HongOoi's suggestion, though that doesn't look so good).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magrittr uses a number of aliases for problems of this nature. Here is an example sequence using the alias `set_names()`

```
data_lists <- 
   paste0("q",2011:2015) %>%
   lapply(.,get) %>%
   set_names(paste0("q",2011:2015))
```

See `?extract` for more aliases

Comment: good lord, was `setNames` not good enough for magrittr? the same package which uses `is_weakly_greater_than` and `is_weakly_less_than` rather than `>=/is_ge` or `<=/is_le`

Comment: I don't follow what you mean.

Comment: the point is that base R already has `setNames`; except for preferring snake to camel case, why bother defining a new function?

Comment: @BenBolker one reason might be because `setNames` is actually part of the stats package, so rather than add a dependency for just this function, the magrittr devs decided to make their own. I do think some of the other aliases are OTT though -- makes your code look like programming in assembler.

Answer (score 4):

Because everything in R is a function (mostly), you could also do

```
data_lists <-
    paste0("q",2011:2015) %>%
    lapply(.,get) %>%
    `names<-`(paste0("q",2011:2015))
```